# Login with Flutter Ktor Rest API

Tags: flutter

I just started writing apps with Flutter. I created a server with Ktor. It works fine when logged in from the app. I check with Token while opening the application. If Response is 200, I programmed it as redirect to the Dashboard screen, if not, redirect to the Login screen. But I feel like there is an error in the codes. It opens slowly. I wanted to get your opinion on this. I am sharing the code samples below

https://gist.github.com/togisoft/a46d449d18f9113d5676da3355300d50

Comment: Your init() method may delay your startup, but im not sure, since you don't await it in the initState. You can try to remove it (looks like debug code)

Comment: Thanks for your answer .I solved this problem with GETX